# how to marker to xAxis when showing monthly charts in hightchart vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, highcharts

I need to mark montly xAxis on highcharts vue[image: like in this image the years are marked on xAxis]

Not able to find any solution regarding to this issue

Comment: Could you please provide your basic chart config and what your data looks like?

Comment: Hey @magdalena thanks for helping, I did find the solution by just adding tickWidth: 1, tickmarkPlacement: 'on' in xAxis.